# How to extract relative path from a URL in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, url, substring, extract

I have an URL and I want to extract everything other than host name. How can this be achieved? For eg:

My string: https://title001-stg.azuge.net/enstgormedia/media/802/titles/123.srt

My requirement: media/802/titles/123.srt

Comment: This is what you need - https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-substring/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of PG's [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html)

For example if you have table and values like the below

```
create table testexample (url varchar);

insert into testexample values ('https://title001-stg.azuge.net/enstgormedia/media/802/titles/123.srt');
insert into testexample values ('https://title002-stg.azuge.net/enstgormedia/media/804/titles/123.srt');
```

You could extract the part you want with

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(url, 'https://[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\/','') from testexample;
```

The regular espression `https://[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\/` mimics the `http://a.b.net/folder/` setup in your example

Comment: In some cases its only picking the half path, is there any way where i can get all the string after hostname.

Comment: If you want everything after the hostname (that btw was not like the example you were showing) you just have to substitute the regular expression `https://[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+.[a-z]+\`